# Dry hopping and massive gas release

Tags: dry-hop, gas

I've been making an American IPA from young's which was sat at 1.010 SG for a couple of days. This is the point at which the instructions suggest I add the hop pellets.

A minute or so after adding the pellets there was a massive release of gas, more than at any point during primary fermentation.

It appears now that there is regular gas being released again, does this mean fermentation has restarted and the hop aromas will be lost? Should I wait for the whole thing to calm down again and add a second batch of hops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fermenting/fermented beer has something like 0.8 volumes of CO₂ dissolved into it.

Adding hops creates a *ton* of nucleation points for CO₂ bubbles to form.

Fermentation has likely not restarted.

You can add the second batch of hops whenever you like.